# Need help on starting the Ignite cache in 2 node cluster

Tags: distributed-caching, ignite

I am novice in Ignite and trying to utilize Ignite to setup in-memory cache. I did some basic configuration and started the Ignite based pluggable persistence work on single node. Now, I am planning to test the performance on 2 node cluster and setting up the ignite configuration as per below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="countryCacheStoreFactory" class="javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder" factory-method="factoryOf">
<constructor-arg><value>com.xyz.exploreignite.cache.CustomCacheStore</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="stateCacheStoreFactory" class="javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder" factory-method="factoryOf">
<constructor-arg><value>com.xyz.exploreignite.cache.CustomStateCacheStore</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="false"/>
<property name="clientMode" value="true"/>
<property name="gridName" value="clusterGrid"/>
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <!-- Partitioned cache example configuration (Atomic mode). -->
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                <property name="backups" value="1"/>
                <property name="name" value="customCountryCache"/>
                <property name="readThrough" value="true"/>
                <property name="writeThrough" value="true"/>
                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                <property name="writeBehindEnabled" value="true"/>
                <property name="copyOnRead" value="true"/>
                <property name="memoryMode" value="OFFHEAP_TIERED"/>
                <property name="atomicWriteOrderMode" value="PRIMARY"/>
                <property name="indexedTypes" >
        <list>
            <value>java.lang.Integer</value>
            <value>com.xyz.exploreignite.pojo.Country</value>
        </list>
        </property>
        <!-- Cache store. -->
        <property name="cacheStoreFactory" ref="countryCacheStoreFactory"/>
            </bean>
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                <property name="backups" value="1"/>
                <property name="name" value="customStateCache"/>
                <property name="readThrough" value="true"/>
                <property name="writeThrough" value="true"/>
                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                <property name="writeBehindEnabled" value="true"/>
                <property name="copyOnRead" value="true"/>
                <property name="memoryMode" value="OFFHEAP_TIERED"/>
                <property name="atomicWriteOrderMode" value="PRIMARY"/>
                <property name="indexedTypes" >
        <list>
            <value>java.lang.Integer</value>
            <value>com.xyz.exploreignite.pojo.State</value>
        </list>
        </property>
        <!-- Cache store. -->
        <property name="cacheStoreFactory" ref="stateCacheStoreFactory"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>


    <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <!--
                    Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                    instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                    to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                -->
                <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">-->
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                            <value>172.26.49.1:47500..47509</value>
                            <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                            <value>172.26.49.2:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now, while starting ignite with "bin/ignite.sh " on both the nodes it shows failed to connect to server. While running only "bin/ignite.sh" in parallel to above one, both the individual ignite config instance starts in standalone mode with only 1 client. I need to have both of them utilizing the shared instance. Please suggest possible issues in my deployment/execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `<value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>` line from the discovery configuration. It doesn't make much for a distributed cluster.

Comment: Already did that and also changed the clientMode to make it false, the application on box 1 gets attached to ignite server, but not box 2, is it necessary to have 2-way communication /ssh connection from Box 2 to Box 1, in order to have cluster formed?

Comment: Yes, two-way communication is required between all nodes including clients or servers. If some of the nodes are behind NAT, you can use `AddressResolver`.

Answer (score 1):

That configuration is in `<property name="clientMode" value="true"/>` You need to have at least one node set to `<property name="clientMode" value="false"/>` or else your clients won't have any server nodes to connect to.